# Aggregation on features in HIVE

Tags: apache-spark, hive

I have a bunch of logs typically of this form:

```
 userID      features
 1           time=4PM,userType=Casual,userType=Business,webSite=ebay
 2           time=6AM,userType=Casual
```

I want to aggregate based on individual features i.e Number of users that logged in at 4AM, Number of casual users, etc.

What I tried was the following - split the userID and divide the features into a certain number of individual feature(s).

```
 userID      features
 1           time=4PM
 1           userType=Casual
 1           userType=Business
 1           webSite=ebay
 2           time=6AM
 2           userType=Casual
```

Now, I can aggregate on individual features and write the computed stats to a file using HiveQL in Spark. Problem with this approach is that I run out of memory in Hive. Is there a better way of aggregating individual features in HIVE?

Comment: Can you show the query you're using which causes you to run out of memory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `regexp_extract` to parse the feature values out of each line without increasing the total number of rows. For a further memory saving, you can save your table in Parquet format:

```
create table logs_columns
   (time string
   ,userType string
   --etc
   )
stored as parquet;

insert into table logs_columns
select userid 
   ,rexexp_extract('time=([^,]*)', features, 1) time
   ,rexexp_extract('userType=([^,]*)', features, 1) userType
   --etc
from logs;
```